A puzzle of two parts
What is the answer to this puzzle?

                                +      -
  
                          -    > <    < >
  
 
                          +    < >    > <    

      

     > <                                 < >

AAACGIMNORTTT → (3,1,2) → ???     EEILNNOPRSSTU → (2,1,4,3) → ¿¿¿¿
   

        
                           Answer: ???¿¿¿¿


I think the final answer is

 MAGNETS

First consider this collection of letters, AAACGIMNORTTT, underneath ><

 The arrows seem to indicate "attraction" and if we remove the letters of ATTRACTION from the sequence of letters it gives AGM or MAG if we re-sort them according to the numbers (3,1,2)

Similarly considering EEILNNOPRSSTU underneath <>

 The arrows seem to indicate "repulsion" and if we remove the letters of REPULSION we get ENST which becomes NETS when rearranged according to the numbers (2,1,4,3)

Putting these together gives

 MAGNETS

This is also clued by

 The table which indicates that opposites attract and likes repel


The also letters almost spell north and south

Very fast, well done!
